# rails view how to render to ftp server in a specific time of day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ftp, periodic-task

The rails system in my company has a view in which we can view and download csv file then ftp the file to a remote server, manually of course. The require of automatically ftp the content(i.e. render the html.erb to a csv file)in mid-night everyday arise and I don't have a clue. Can anyone help ? a hint or maybe a gem ?

Thaanks

my code like:
in controller

```
def invoice_list
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data Invoice.to_csv }
    end
end
```

invoices model

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      Invoice.where("created_at > Date.yesterday").each do |invoice|
          csv << invoice.attributes.values_at(*column_names)  
      end
    end
end
```

Normally, user request the page and push a button on browser to download the csv file. Then ftp the downloaded file to a remote server for further processing manually. Now user require that the whole process, including download csv file, can be started at 12:00AM everyday automatically. I hope this would be clearer for what I need.

Comment: You need to reword "The require of automatically ftp the content(i.e. render the html.erb to a csv file)in mid-night everyday arise and I don't have a clue". It is not clear.  And some code would be nice if there is in logic involved.

Comment: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

One of our system engineer solves the issue,

He just add an action like

```
def upload_invoice
  require 'net/ftp'
  require 'stringio'

  content = Invoice.to_csv
  f = StringIO.new(content)

  host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
  user = "your username"
  password = "password"
  filename = "invoices_#{DateTime.now.to_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")}"

  ftp = Net::FTP.new(host, user, password)
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.storlines("STOR #{filename}", f)
  ftp.close
  f.close
  render nothing: true
end
```

and add this job at crontab run at a specific time everyday:

```
curl -XPOST "https://www.yoursite.com/yourpath/upload_invoice"
```

that's it.